# Powershell Run History Removal

Tags: powershell, registry

I'm trying to run a Powershell script to clear the Run History through the registry.  It works great, but the problem I'm having is that I want it to display the Registry Value Data but I can't get it to display properly.  Here is the script:

```
function Delete
{
$Reg = Get-RegistryValues 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU'
foreach ($Value in $Reg)
    {
    $Item = Get-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU\' -name $Value
    $yes = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Yes",""
    $no = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&No",""
    $choices = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($yes,$no)
    $caption = "Warning!"
    $message = ("Do you want to delete the run value "+$Item)
    $result = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($caption,$message,$choices,0)
    if($result -eq 0) 
        {              
        Remove-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU' -name $Value 
        }
    if($result -eq 1) { }
    }
}

function Get-RegistryValues($Key) 
{
(Get-Item $Key).GetValueNames()

}

Delete
```

Whenever I try to run this I get the following output for the $Message

```
Do you want to delete the run value @{MRULIST=idhgfcaeb}
```

Does anyone know of a way to get JUST the Value Data, so it would be:

```
idhgfcaeb
```

Working solution:

```
function Delete
{
$Reg = Get-RegistryValues 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU'
foreach ($Value in $Reg)
    {
    if ($Value -eq 'MRUList') {Set-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU\' -name $Value -value ' '}
    Else 
        {
        $Item = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU\' -name $Value).$Value.TrimEnd("\1")
        $yes = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Yes",""
        $no = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&No",""
        $choices = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($yes,$no)
        $caption = "Warning!"
        $message = ("Do you want to delete the run value "+$Item)
        $result = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($caption,$message,$choices,0)
        if($result -eq 0) 
            {              
            Remove-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU' -name $Value 
            }
        if($result -eq 1) { }
        }
    }
}

function Get-RegistryValues($Key) 
{
(Get-Item $Key).GetValueNames()
}

Delete
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
$Item = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU\' -Name mrulist).MRUList
```

Or:

```
("Do you want to delete the run value " + $Item.MRUList)
```

Comment: Using the $Item.$Value gives me a broken down version.  I'm wondering if there's anything that can be done about the \1 at the end:

Now it's coming up: cmd\1 mspaint\1 for the values.

Comment: What variable is giving you that?

Comment: When I have $Item.$Value it adds the \1 to the end of everything that appears.  I with there was a $_.TrimEnd to take care of that.

Comment: I figured out that part, I added an extra line to set the Variable.

`.$Value.TrimEnd("\1")` to the `'$Item = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU\' -Name $Value)`